# How to Dynamically Change MDDataTable Values

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

```
    from kivy.metrics import dp
    from kivy.clock import Clock
    from kivymd.app import MDApp
    from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable

    from kivy.lang import Builder
    from kivy.core.window import Window
    Window.size = (1920, 1080)
    KV = '''

FloatLayout:
    MDRaisedButton:
        text: "Strategies Using Date Only"
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .10}
        on_release : app.create_table()
        elevation: 12

    MDCard:
        id: card   
        size_hint: None, None
        size: "1000dp", "1000dp"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .8}
        ripple_behavior: True
        elevation: 12


'''


class Example(MDApp):
    r_data = [('3100','20.5')]
    c_data = [('Strike Price',dp(30)),('Price',dp(30))]
    i = 0
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def on_start(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_table,0.5)
        

    def on_row_press(self, instance_table, instance_row):
        '''Called when a table row is clicked.'''

        print(instance_table, instance_row)

    def on_check_press(self, instance_table, current_row):
        '''Called when the check box in the table row is checked.'''

        print(instance_table, current_row)

    
    
    def create_table(self):
        self.data_tables = MDDataTable(
            id = 'table',
            size_hint=(0.9, 0.6),
            use_pagination=True,
            check=True,
            column_data=self.c_data,
            row_data=self.r_data,
        )
        self.data_tables.bind(on_row_press=self.on_row_press)
        self.data_tables.bind(on_check_press=self.on_check_press)
        self.root.ids.card.add_widget(self.data_tables)
    
    def update_table(self, *args):
        
        self.r_data = [(str(3100+self.i),str(20.5+self.i))]
        self.i += 1
        try:
            self.root.ids.card.clear_widgets()
            self.create_table()
        except:
            pass

        

Example().run()
```

I am using this code to change the row values of the data table. However, I am not able to checkmark the row. Is there is another way to do this?
Basically, I am trying to make a data table for `hft` data, and I want to modify the data table in runtime. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Problem]

Could somebody help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As of now in the current latest stable version 0.104.1 of KivyMD this is not possible yet.

You can also see this warning message on the Data Tables documentation page.

"Warning

Data tables are still far from perfect. Errors are possible and we hope you inform us about them."